# PLS HELP PHP syntax

Tags: php, html

Here's my form

```
<form id="place-bid" action="placebid.php?placeBidProductId='.$row['product_id'].'" method="post" >
                        Your Bid:<br>
    <input type="text"  placeholder="$$$" name="money">
    <input type="Submit" class="button_bid" name="submit" value="Place Bid">
    <input type=hidden id='rowid' value=".row['product_id']." name='row_id'>
</form>
```

and here is my placebid.php

```
<?php
   // $product_id=$_GET['placeBidProductId'];
   $product_id=$_POST['row_id'];
   echo " Id Produs : ".$product_id;
?>
```

My problem: I can't get the value from `$row['product_id']`, it will only echo the string `"$row['product_id'] .$product_id;"`

Comment: What were you expecting it to return? You have set your form to that exact value. If you are trying to make the form using the results of a query from a database you need to show us more of your code. As it stands what you are getting is exactly what you are providing in your form.

Comment: I know that I should show you more but it would sound like a story . I work with xampp. I have a database and some tables. One of them is called products(int product_id,varchar product_name,product_description,category_id FK to Categories table,seller_id, and also a column called img whic type is BLOB); I made a HTML file which display all the products from a specific category. Every product has a form for bidding ( because its an Online Auction App) and when the button "Place Bid" is pressed i want to insert in a table called bids the product_id. I will post all my code here

Comment: You already have an answer that you said works so there is no need to post more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that before you are outputting that form you are doing some sort of query of a database. If that is the case then you likely want to change this line

```
<input type=hidden id='rowid' value=".row['product_id']." name='row_id'>
```

to

```
<input type=hidden id='rowid' value="<?php echo row['product_id'];>" name='row_id'>
```

Comment: <input type=hidden id='rowid' value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" name='row_id'>

Comment: That line of code made it work. Thanks a lot.. You really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Use print_r($_POST) for all form post value on form action page i.e. placebid.php. it will show you all value in form. Then make you business logic accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for replying but it s a little bit confusing. I write this print_r($_POST) in my placebid.php and when i press the button of the form it shows me something like this : Array ( [money] => [submit] => Place Bid [row_id] => .row['product_id']. )

Comment: row['product_id']  has a specific value ( an integer ) and because of that " " and ' '  i can t get the proper value.. All I get is the string.. i dont know how to explain myself

Comment: Add echo "<pre>"; to view human readable data on browser. Also put some value in text input field before form submit. I hope it helps.